# How to use @font-face from fonts that added to my project?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a font file in font directory of my project and use it to css file,in my system working true but not working in the client system.how to use it that correct result ?

my font-face in css is :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Yekan';
    src: url('font/Yekan.eot');
    src: url('Font/Yekan.woff');
    src: url('Font/Yekan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/Yekan.ttf'),  url('font/Yekan.svg');
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

My font path is :

[image]

Comment: If you have a re-create, then take a look at the networks tab of the browser's developer tools. Likely you'll find there is a problem with the get request. I expect you're including that `@font-face` in a file that is not in the parent folder of the `Font` folder.

Comment: Also note, you're not consistent with the casing of `Font`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try creating a web font

https://www.web-font-generator.com/

Comment: thanks for help me,but how to determine path of font after creating font by it?

Comment: It automatically creates a preview.html for you with instructions. Just download the .zip package and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all the ' ' from the css.

This should work for you.